# WCF Sage Accpac 6.0 login error

Tags: c#, wcf, accpac

I'm developing WCF with VS 2010 for Sage ACCPAC 6.0 , but when trying to login with valid login credentials , still the inner exception says invalid sign on information , the code is listed below , need some help.

The UserBL._accpacSession.Open method returns an Exception

**WCF server code**

```
public class ACCPACLoginServiceManager : IACCPACLogInService
    {
        public bool InitiateConnection(string papplicationID, string pprogramName, string pprogrameVersion, string user, string password, string company, ref string errMsg)
        {
            try
            {
                UserBL.applicationID = papplicationID;
                UserBL.programName = pprogramName;
                UserBL.programeVersion = pprogrameVersion;

                UserBL._userID = user;
                UserBL._userPassword = password;
                UserBL._companyID = company;
                UserBL._accpacSession = new Session();
                UserBL._accpacSession.Init("", UserBL.applicationID, UserBL.programName, UserBL.programeVersion);
                UserBL._accpacSession.EnforceAppVersion = false;
                UserBL._accpacSession.Open(UserBL._userID, UserBL._userPassword, UserBL._companyID, DateTime.Now, 0);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                errMsg = error.Message;
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                UserBL._accpacSession.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }
```

**WCF Client code**

```
string VERSION = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCPAC_VERSION"].Trim();
        string USERID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCPAC_BD_USERID"].Trim();
        string PASSWORD = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCPAC_DB_PASSWORD"].Trim();

string MAINDB = "DXDXDT";

 accpaclogin.InitiateConnection("AS", "AS1000", VERSION, USERID, PASSWORD, MAINDB, ref errMsg);
```

**line of code works for Windows Application without WCF code (standalone application without IIS , with the same parameters given) , so it seems that it is NOT the User name , password or Company name issue (I have hard coded the values under WCF server application same issue is there )
Hope for a better answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making the application pool change , make the trick for me

[image]